# Question about the 90/180 Schengen visa rule

Tags: visas, schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

Good evening lovely StackExchange forum!

First of all sorry if this question has been asked already, I didn't find an appropriate answer searching through the internet on my own and got confused a lot.

I've met someone who doesn't have an European passport.. and of course I fell in love with her and want to meet her again. She luckily decided the same. She entered the Schengen Area on the 03.10 and left on 12.12.2018, so she stayed for 71 days and her 180 days period ends on the 31.03 if I am counting correctly.

So my question is, could she use those leftover 19 days to "extend" her upcoming new tourist visa? Like arriving the 13.03, using the 19 days and then start the new 90/180 days period. If yes, does she has to stay 1 day out of the Schengen Area and reenter, or what would you suggest to take care about/ how to do it?

Thanks a lot for any answer in advance, you will help in the name of love haha

Trebuh

The edit:

Hello, I still don't find an appropriate answer on my own or I seem to not understand the other answers properly, I am not a native speaker and got problems with the level of explanation of some of the answers. Also it would be very nice if you answer my actual question, as the 180 day period never ends / there is no single 180- day period doesn't help me, it confuses me as I find different opinions about that. I was simply asking if the given case is possible and if yes, if she has to leave the Schengen room for a day. The question is really easy. Thank you.

Comment: The 180 day period never ends - it works on a rolling basis.

Comment: There is no single 180-day period. The rule applies to every possible 180-day period: the one that started 179 days ago, the one that started 178 days ago, ..., the one that started yesterday, ...

Comment: Please read the linked question, and if there is something specific you don't understand edit the question to ask about that.

Comment: This is what it means: The next time she re-enters the Schengen area *before a certain date,* she can stay for up to 19 days.  If she waits until the certain date, she can enter for up to 90 days.  In her case, the certain date is 13 March, if I got the math right.  Check at the Schengen calculator.  (The certain date is a number of days after her first entry, where the number is 180 less the number of unused days of presence, so 180-19 is 161, and 13 March is the 161st day after 3 Oct in a non-leap year.)

Comment: @phoog Hello and thank you for your answer. I am really sorry that I still don't understand you to 100%. As I understand you, you are telling me that she can enter the 13th of March and stay for 19 days, then stay for another 90 days? If yes, does she has to leave the Schengen for a night? Sorry for that confusion, but I am confused.

Comment: The [Schengen calculator](https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en) agrees. She can arrive on 13 March and stay for up to 90 days. She does not have to leave and re-enter to enable this.  If she enters on 13 March, she must leave on or before 10 June, the 90th day.  She cannot combine the 19 days with some other 90 days and thereby get a 109-day visit.  That's because on every day of presence, you have to look at that day along with the previous 179 days.  If she stays until 11 June, then she'll have 91 days of presence.

Comment: @phoog That is a very qualified and clear answer which actually helps me. Thank you a lot, you solved it!